# HTML dosn't work correctly WITH laravel pdf

Tags: php, html, laravel, pdf, dompdf

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YwNr7.png)

```
public function Repas_etq()
    {
        $pdf = App::make('dompdf.wrapper');
        $customPaper = array(0,0,595,842);
        $date=date('Y-m-d');
        $repas_pdj = DB::table('fiche_repas')->WHERE('date_planif',$date)->WHERE('repas','LIKE',"%".$_GET['repas']."%")->get();

        $html="<html><head><title>Etiquettes </title>
        <meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=utf-8'/>
        <style>
        @page{ padding:0px;}
            span.etq 
            {
                
                display: inline-block;
                width: 65mm;
                height: 30mm;
                
                border:solid 1px red;
                background-color: yellow; 
                
            }
        </style>
        </head>
        <body>";
        
        $html.="<div>";
        foreach($repas_pdj as $pdj)
        {   
            
        
                $html.="<span class='etq'>".$pdj->id."</span>";
                
            
        }
        $html.="</div>";
      
        $html.="</body></html>";    
       
        $pdf->loadHTML($html);
        
        $pdf->setPaper($customPaper)->setWarnings(false)->Output('myfile.pdf','F');
       
        return $pdf->stream();
       
    }
```

Hey friends,
When i use css "display: inline-block;" and html with laravel dompdf i get a bad result please some help  to get the good result
is there some 1 to give me some advices , thanks

Comment: It seems your `setPaper` does not kick in, it's still at 210mm X 297mm. That is why your span is getting "pushed" to the next row -  `3 * 65mm + 6 * 0.26 mm + bleed > 210mm` (The 6 * 0.26mm is the border thickness if the DPI is set to 96)

Comment: even if i change width i get the same result :/

Comment: In what way is the HTML not rendering correctly? A newer release of Dompdf (1.1.1) is available, you may want to try upgrading.